# Play 2.2.2 standalone deployable crashes

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I've done a clean, stage and dist inside the play console. After I unzip the folder created I go to the start script in the bin folder. Double click the script, it pops up for a split second and closes. Same thing happens if I run with administrator.

What would cause this? How would I go about fixing it?

EDIT: Also I've checked my path variables, not the problem. Also, I managed to grab a gif of what happens when I run it:

[image: Imgur]

Upon closer investigation, I found the frame of what it says:

"The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect."
[image: Imgur]

Hopefully this is more helpful, I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Did you instal the latest jdk?

Comment: Yes I have the JDK... I can run it fine, deploy to something like Heroku fine, just can't make a standalone.
EDIT: Does it matter which version of Java 7 it is? The Play documentation doesn't mention this so I assume not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429234/play-framework-2-stage-task-on-windows-the-input-line-is-too-long ?

Comment: Ah it appears we do have the same bug, is there a way we can close this? Also thanks Marco!

Comment: Try to edit the script file and delimit a line, append the ^ character to the line. Eg: line1 ^
line2 ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments pointed out this is a known issue, some workarounds/answers can be found here [Play Framework 2 Stage Task on Windows, "The input line is too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429234/play-framework-2-stage-task-on-windows-the-input-line-is-too-long)