# Play framework 2.3 - cannot start in production

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

When I run my Play app using `activator start` I get the following error:

```
(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background )

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Every thing works when running in dev mode using `run`. I'm not quite sure where to look to fix this, what might the issue be?

Comment: Can you share Activator version?

Comment: Activator 1.2.10, I'm just about to install Activator 1.3.2 but i don't think this will make a difference, I just mention it for more complete info. I'm going to deploy on a linux machine eventually so I think that that will solve the issues. I am yet to try any of sebster's suggestions on Windows but I will do that asap.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue caused by long variables beying generated when the project directory structure is too long.

Long story short: it's a **cmd.exe** [limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473).

See [Activator start does not works for JDK 8 on windows 7](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/708) **and** [Activator start errror - Bad application path: -Dhttp.port=9000](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3081)

**Solution(s):**

- Put your project on a short path like C:\your_project_name.
- Or, try [lampz](https://github.com/lampz)'s solution(same underlying problem):

> Windows solution:
>
> 1 - "activator stage" in the command line
>
> 2 - Copy the stage directory from target\universal\stage to c:\stage
>   to avoid issues with long file paths
>
> 3 - To avoid the Bad Application Path issues just create a new .bat
>   file with the following (my project is called proj): set
>   PROJ_OPTS="-Dconfig.file=../conf/application.conf" proj.bat
>
> Note: change PROJ_OPTS to YOURPROJECTNAME_OPTS and proj.bat to
>   yourprojectname.bat

See also: [Play Framework 2 Stage Task on Windows, “The input line is too long”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429234/play-framework-2-stage-task-on-windows-the-input-line-is-too-long)

Comment: I tried all the solutions and it made no difference. I will get my hands on a linux machine soon and hopefully that will work but it's a bit annoying that I can't get it to work on Windows. i'm a bit stuck with this one.

Comment: I assume that this is also to do with the classpath being too long (because of the long dir structure). I used wildcards for the classpath in the `.bat` file but it made no difference.

Comment: "I assume that this is also to do with the classpath being too long" -> quite possible and it would explain why none of the solutions solved the problem for some users.

Comment: As for the linux machine... it will work and compilation will be noticeably faster as well.

Comment: One more thing. Did you do a clean, reload, recompile after changing the project location? Cause that should regenerate your classpath.

Comment: Ahh no i didn't. I'll try that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you production code using activator and run it with the following command -

```
java -Dhttp.port=9000 %1 -cp "lib/*;" play.core.server.NettyServer .
```