# Building runnable jar with play framework

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm attempting to build a runnable jar from source built using akka/play/java.

I'm running into a bunch of issues and haven't been able to solve any.

I've tried using `sbt dist` which builds out the sh and bat. However the bat can't actually be run and the sh gives an `Error: Could not find or load main class play.core.server.ProdServerStart` error.

I also attempted to run it using `java -cp "target\universal\untitled1-1.0\lib\*" play.core.server.ProdServerStart` which results in `java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf`

Then I've also tried using `sbt assemby` which throws `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'play.application'` I'm completely lost on how to actually build a runnable jar on Windows for play.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the bat can't actually be run"? As you're on Windows, you should be able to run the .bat file created by play dist. What error do you get?

Comment: I get the `The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect.` error. I've seen it in a few github tickets for sbt, but don't see it resolved anywhere. I'm using play 2.5.9 btw.

Comment: @lutzh, well I spent about 4 hours last night tring to resolve the issue and figured it out in about 10 minutes today. Solution is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429234/play-framework-2-stage-task-on-windows-the-input-line-is-too-long